# Facebook like Popup information/message/alert system with AJAX and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, facebook, popup

What would be best method to show a popup message box (like facebook) using ajax? (Where in I can place form submit/cancel buttons, and other operations) I have message form & processing code in seperate file as I dont want to place it inline in every page. (light and fast). I have tried a few, and boxy was a good one, but have some problems using Boxy too. What could be the best, fast and still light in code.
And also I will be validating the form from client side, as well as from server side, and display the error , if any, on that same modal popup box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created my own version of a Lightweight Modal popup plugin.
POPELT - http://welbour.com/labs/popelt/

It is lightweight, supports nested popups, object oriented, supports dynamic buttons, responsive, and lot more.
Next update will include Popup Ajax form submissions etc.

Feel free to use and tweet feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the facebook popups, just use: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/, this way you will have light and fast code on each page of your site.

Or you can create your own modals using http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/.  They have multiple styles you can use and also work with AJAX.

Comment: Thnx for the info. I wouldn't prefer jqueryui dialogs as they are heavy in size, performance matters. I am now using Boxy dialogs (minified it to 13KB). It is very effective and almost what I needed. But repeated use of AJAX in it created problem in firefox. that's where I'm stuck :(

Comment: Contact the makers of Boxy to see if they have a firefox fix.

Comment: No I didn't get a solution yet.

Comment: They didn't had any answer. 
I created my own plugin